# Wordpress Get URL Footer File

Tags: php, html, wordpress, url

I need to access the footer inside a wordpress theme via a url. Ideally it would just render the footer data and nothing else, alternative suggestions welcomed though.

To add some context, the data will be fetched through the url and a script will read the markup. This data will then be cached and available through Magento where it is needed to be displayed..

Is there a url path that will display it or should I make a new page that can be called via the base-url+the-page-name???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you can do is make a wordpress custom page template.

If you dont know how heres a little tutorial : http://www.expand2web.com/blog/custom-page-template-wordpress/

Now you want the custom page template to only load the footer (add the html, head and body opening tags yourself)

if you create a new page with your page template seletced it will only output the footer.

Hope you can get it to work

Greetings

merijn

Comment: cheers mate, as it happened this worked out to be the best solution for my situation.

Answer (score 3):

There's nothing built in to do that. You could use the [AJAX API](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins) in your theme or a plugin and accomplish it.

You hook into an `action` that gets sent as a URL or POST data parameter and then make a request to `yoursite.com/path/to/wordpress/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php`.

```
<?php
add_action('wp_ajax_so20495429_display_footer', 'so20495429_display_footer');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_so20495429_display_footer', 'so20495429_display_footer');
function so20495429_display_footer()
{
    get_footer('ajax');
}
```

This will work for all users, logged in or not, despite the `wp-admin` URL. [Here is code above wrapped up in a plugin](https://github.com/chrisguitarguy/WPSE-Plugins/blob/master/ajax-footer.php).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How exactly do I implement this? I tried adding the code to this file and viewed it in the browser but it doesn't return any data. I'm sure I'm missing something obvious but any more details that you can give me would be great. Thank you

Comment: You can drop it into your `functions.php` or a plugin. Then visit `yoursite.com/path/to/wordpress/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=so20495429_display_footer`.

Answer (score 0):

What about `$footer_url=get_template_directory_uri().'/footer.php';` ?

Comment: The WordPress environment isn't set up if you do that. Use any WordPress funtions in your `footer.php` and this doesn't work.